# MySQL - Calculating Percentile Ranks on the fly

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL SELECT query which uses 20 different comparisons within the same table. Here's an example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (col1 > (col2 * 0.25))
AND (col5 < col10) .......
```

I'm trying to calculate percentile ranks based on the order of a column called `SCORE` within the `SELECT` results returned. I've tried using incremental row numbers and `COUNT(*)` to get the stock's rank and total number of results returned but not sure how to assign the same rank where some of the results have the same `SCORE`.

Here's the formula that I'm trying to calculate:

```
((COUNT(lower scores) + (COUNT(same/tied scores) / 2)) * 100) / COUNT(total results)
```

How do I find the number of lower scores, same/tied scores and total scores within the same result row for calculating percentiles on the fly?

I'm trying to avoid using stored procedures because I want to my application's admins to tailor the SELECT statement within my applications admin area as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Shlomi's code above, here's the code that I came up with to calculate percentile ranks (in case anyone wants to calculate these in the future):

```
SELECT 
    c.id, c.score, ROUND(((@rank - rank) / @rank) * 100, 2) AS percentile_rank
FROM
    (SELECT 
    *,
        @prev:=@curr,
        @curr:=a.score,
        @rank:=IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank + 1) AS rank
    FROM
        (SELECT id, score FROM mytable) AS a,
        (SELECT @curr:= null, @prev:= null, @rank:= 0) AS b
ORDER BY score DESC) AS c;
```

Comment: is there a simple way to turn this statement into an UPDATE statement? For example say I have a column called "percentile" in mytable, is there a way to modify the statement to store the percentile_rank result in the percentile column for each row?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a post (of mine) which explains ranking during `SELECT`: [SQL: Rank without Self Join](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-ranking-without-self-join).

It uses user defined variables which are accessed and assigned even as the rows are being iterated.

Using the same logic, it could be extended to include numbers of total scores, distinct scores etc. As a preview, here's a typical query:

```
SELECT
  score_id, student_name, score,
  @prev := @curr,
  @curr := score,
  @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank
FROM
  score,
  (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0) sel1
ORDER BY score DESC
;
```

Comment: Hi Shlomi. Thanks for your reply. This certainly helps but it does not provide total ranks on each row to calculate the percentile. Any idea how I can do that? I posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545537/mysql-selecting-total-results-returned-in-each-row to figure that out but still not getting anywhere.

Comment: To illustrate briefly, add another variable which gets accumulated (@total_rank := @total_rank + @current_rank). Then wrap the entrie query with an outer query, which can now use rank/@total_rank. I hope this brief description helps.

Answer (score 1):

The responses from Shlomi and Zishan (which uses Shlomi's code) definitely do not give accurate results, as I discovered by examining the results on a large table of mine. As answered elsewhere, it is apparently impossible to calculate percentile ranks in a single MySQL query:
[SQL rank percentile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241247/sql-rank-percentile/27649407#27649407)

The Shlomi Noach approach using user-defined variables does **- at first - look** like it's working fine for the top couple percent of rankings, but it quickly degenerates for the lower-ranking rows in your table. Look at your data results for yourself, as I did.

See this blog post by Roland Bouman about why Shlomi's approach using user-defined variables **within a single SQL statement** doesn't work, with a proposed better solution:

http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2009/09/mysql-another-ranking-trick.html

So then I adapted Bouman's code for this purpose and here's my solution, which necessarily combines PHP and MySQL:

Step 1) Calculate and store the absolute rank for each row by submitting the following two queries:

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len := @@max_allowed_packet;

UPDATE mytable INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, FIND_IN_SET(
    score,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
             DISTINCT score
             ORDER BY score  DESC
            )
        FROM mytable)
        ) AS rank
FROM mytable) AS a
ON mytable.ID=a.ID
SET mytable.rank = rank;
```

Step 2: Fetch the total number of rows (and store the result in a PHP variable $total)

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM mytable
```

Step 3: Use a PHP loop to iterate through the table to use the absolute rank for each row to calculate the row's percentile rank:

3a) Loop through:

```
SELECT ID, rank FROM mytable
```

while storing those row values as $ID and $rank in PHP

3b) For each row run:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE mytable INNER JOIN (
            SELECT (100*COUNT(ID)/'.$total.') percentile
            FROM mytable
            WHERE rank >= '.$rank.'
        ) a 
        ON mytable.ID = a.ID
        WHERE mytable.ID='.$ID.'
        SET mytable.percentile = a.percentile';
```

Probably not the most efficient process, but definitely accurate, and since in my case the 'score' value is not updated very often, so I run the above script as a cron batch operation to keep the percentile ranks up-to-date.