# MySql - Selecting Total Results Returned In Each Row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count total number of results on each row of my `SELECT` query. Something like:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM mytable;
```

But this returns just a single row with the count. How do I get the total number of returned rows on every row?

I've tried achieve this using: SELECT @i=@i+1 (in a sub query) but it doesn't work. Also, tried grouping by id but that doesn't help either.

Is there some MySql function that returns total number of rows returned so that it could be added into each row of the result (for calculations)?

Comment: What do you mean by "total number of results on each row" ?  It sounds like you want to SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY id; but you say you did try it. Can you provide info about your table and the desired results?

Comment: could you provide sample data and output expecting from it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable) FROM mytable;
```

Maybe you mean something like this?

Comment: suppose there are 5 rows then for each id you will get output as `1, 5`, `2, 5`, .... which I believe OP doesn't want and that result either won't make sense...

Comment: Yes, I was guessing he meant this by "the total number of returned rows on every row"

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your answers. Yes - I'm trying to get output as `1, 5`, `2, 5`... but a nested SELECT query can't be used because it would be too costly if I want the total number of rows within a large query on a large table with around 10k or more records. Is there any other work around?

Comment: Have you tried an EXPLAIN of the query? If you are using MyISAM storage engine then the count will be optimized. Otherways you should simply put the count result into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `GROUP BY id`

Use this

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY id;
```