# MySQL - Percentile calculation and update it in other column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, percentile

I have a table in MySQL (phpMYAdmin) with the following columns

[image: MySQL Table]

I am trying to determine the percentile for each row and update that value in the G1Ptile column. G1Ptile column is the percentile calculation based on G1%. I am using the following based on John Woo's answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241247/sql-rank-percentile)

```
SELECT  `G1%`, 
       (1-ranks/totals)*100 Percentile FROM (
SELECT  distinct `G1%`,
        @rank:=@rank + 1 ranks,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PCount) totals
FROM    PCount a,
        (SELECT @rank:=0) s
ORDER   BY `G1%` DESC ) s;
```

and get the following output

[image: Output]

The output is in a select statement, I want to be able to update it to the G1Ptile column in my table, however I am unable to update it using

```
UPDATE `PCount` SET `G1Ptile`= --(All of the select query mentioned above)
```

Can you please help with modifying the query/suggest an alternative so that I can use the percentile values obtained using the above query and update it into G1Ptile in the same table. One more problem I have is that there are two 20% values in G1%, however the percentile assigned to one is 20 and other is 30. I want both of them to be 20 and the next row in the series to be 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write your calculation as:

```
SELECT `G1%`, 
       (1 - ranks / totals) * 100 as Percentile
FROM (SELECT `G1%`,
              (@rank := @rank + 1) ranks,
              (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PCount) as totals
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `G1%`
            FROM PCount
            ORDER BY `G1%` DESC
           ) p CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT COUNT(*) as totals, @rank := 0
            FROM Pcount
           ) params
     ) p;
```

I made certain changes more consistent with how MySQL processes variables.  In particular, the `SELECT DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` are in a subquery.  This is necessary in more recent versions of MySQL (although in the most recent you can use window functions).

This can now be incorporated into an update using `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE PCount p JOIN
       (SELECT `G1%`, 
                (1 - ranks / totals) * 100 as Percentile
        FROM (SELECT `G1%`,
                      (@rank := @rank + 1) ranks,
                      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PCount) as totals
              FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `G1%`
                    FROM PCount
                    ORDER BY `G1%` DESC
                   ) p CROSS JOIN
                   (SELECT COUNT(*) as totals, @rank := 0
                    FROM Pcount
                   ) params
             ) pp
       ) pp
       ON pp.`G1%` = p.`G1%`
    SET p.G1Ptile = pp.percentile;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon, unfortunately I get an error while running your query. Can you please advise. 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM p) pp
       ) pp
       ON pp.`G1%` = p.`G1%`
    SET ' at line 15

Comment: @Quark . . . That row should have been deleted.  I decided to put the logic in `params.

Comment: Gordon, your solution works well, my G1Ptile table has been updated with the percentile, however I noticed that the percentiles begin at 20 if I have two similar G1% values, the percentiles begin at 60 if I have 6 similar values and so on. I removed DISTINCT from your query, however that shows the percentiles as 0,10,20,80*6,90... I do not expect you to provide me ready made queries, however I will appreciate if you could please explain the query a little so I can try to modify it to meet my requirements.

Comment: Can I do something like DISTINCT totals?

Comment: @Quark . . . You probably want `count(distinct "G1%''`